# Why does specifying the prop's object's attributes does not work?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I had already found a solution by luck so I don't quite understand how it worked even after trying to read stuff online.

I am simply trying to get the array of comments inside the selectedDish prop. The selectedDish's state is populated inside the Main Component's function, and I am trying to access selectedDish's array of comments inside the DishDetail component.

I was able to get the comments by:

```
{ this.props.selectedDish && this.renderComments(this.props.selectedDish.comments)}
```

But I am unable to when I just do the following and receive this error "Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined":

```
{ this.renderComments(this.props.selectedDish.comments)}
```

Why does this work? Shouldn't `this.props.selectedDish.comments` be enough as I am able to successfully render the "renderDish(dish)" function?

**Main Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import Dishdetail from './DishdetailComponent';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';

class Main extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        dishes: DISHES,
        selectedDish: null
    };
   // this.onDishSelect = this.onDishSelect.bind(this);
  }

  onDishSelect(dishId) {
    this.setState({
       selectedDish: dishId
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar dark color="primary">
          <div className="container">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
          </div>
        </Navbar>

        <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} onClick={(dishId) => this.onDishSelect(dishId)} />
        <Dishdetail selectedDish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === this.state.selectedDish)[0]} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

**DishDetail Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';

export default class Dishdetail extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    renderDish(dish) {

        if (dish != null)
            return (
                <Card >
                    <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                        <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            );
        else
            return (
                <div></div>
            );
    }

    renderComments(comments) {
        let list = (<div></div>);
        if (comments != null) {
            list = (
                <ul className="list-unstyled">
                    {comments.map(c => {
                        return (
                            <li key={c.id}>
                                <p>{c.comment}</p>
                                <p>-- {c.author}, {new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: '2-digit' }).format(new Date(Date.parse(c.date)))}</p>
                            </li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
            );
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h4>Comments</h4>
                {list}
            </div>
        );

    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="row">

                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    {this.renderDish(this.props.selectedDish)}
                </div>

                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    {/* This works: */}
                    { this.props.selectedDish && this.renderComments(this.props.selectedDish.comments)}

                    {/* This doesn't:  */}
                    {/* { this.renderComments(this.props.selectedDish.comments)} */}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your main component renders for the first time the `props` are still `undefined` as DISHES haven't been loaded, reasons for that might be the DISHES are initiated with some external resource.

So when `this.props.selectedDish` is `undefined` you can't access it's key because they don't exist. So react throws this error.

```
{ this.props.selectedDish && this.renderComments(this.props.selectedDish.comments)}
```

So this ensures `this.props.selectedDish` exists and then you are accessing it's `comments` key.

Answer (score 1):

When your component is loaded the first time the `selectedDish` state value is null. It only gets set later, hence the error.

Changing the below code

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        dishes: DISHES,
        selectedDish: null
    };
   // this.onDishSelect = this.onDishSelect.bind(this);
  }
```

To

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        dishes: DISHES,
        selectedDish: {}
    };
   // this.onDishSelect = this.onDishSelect.bind(this);
  }
```

will make it work. However I feel that what you are doing now i.e. null check and then render is a more robust way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few pointers , you don't need to have a class based component since you aren't using lifecycle methods etc.
you can use destructuring to reduce typing 
`let {selectedDish:{comments}} = this.props .`

You could solve your problem with a default value for comments ,

```
`const Dishdetail = ({selectedDishes:{comments}}=[]}) => {}
```

and conditional rendering in render

```
<div>
{ comments.length > 0 &&
   //map you comments here if you have some

}
</div>`
```